# Alterações no código foram apagadas dentro do VS CODE

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

Boa noite! Acabei de fazer várias alterações em meu projeto da faculdade, então cliquei em Source Control para enviar para o git. Quando eu estava digitando no commit message, algo deu errado. Não sei se foi algum erro no vs code ou mesmo se apertei um botão ou cliquei em algo que não deveria sem perceber... O fato é que todas as alterações que eu tinha feito foram apagadas e os arquivos voltaram ao que estava antes de todo o trabalho ser feito.

Alguém sabe dizer o que pode ter acontecido e principalmente se é possível recuperar essa parte perdida do código? Nenhum arquivo foi excluído, apenas todas as alterações que eu fiz hoje no projeto se apagaram dentro do VS Code, enquanto eu tentava enviar para o github.

Desculpem se eu não tiver sido clara na explicação, mas realmente não tenho ideia do que aconteceu  para poder ser mais detalhada.

Comment: *"Não sei se foi algum erro no vs code ou mesmo se apertei um botão ou cliquei em algo que não deveria .."* *"Alguém sabe dizer o que pode ter acontecido.."* fica difícil de dizer, pra "perder" as changes os possíveis problemas são: -fez stash pq havia algum confito, - fez algum reset do repositório, mas fica difícil de ajudar se tu não sabe o que fez... tente alterar 1 linha de código e replicar o problema e coloque os detalhes aqui

Comment: Obrigada por responder. Eu tentei, mas não aconteceu o mesmo dessa vez. Infelizmente para mim, vou ter que refazer tudo.

Answer (score -3):

1 - Você estava registrando as alterações (commits)?

[image: Print do Local de Registrar alterações]

se sim, use o comando "git status" para ver seu último registro :D